# How to go through whole resource file in wpf. Find all keys and make Images from that keys

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose i have few Resource Dictionaries in my project.
They named like 1,2,3 etc... From code behind i want to go to "1" resource file, find all "x:keys" and make by that key Image...
every Resource Dictionary file looks like this, but have many of such linings of code:

```
  <DrawingImage x:Key="Image1"  x:Name="Image1">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 H64 H0 Z">
                <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0.091821998357772827" Y="0" />
                </DrawingGroup.Transform>
                <DrawingGroup Opacity="1" Transform="1,0,0,1,1,1.01">
                    <DrawingGroup Transform="1,0,0,1,6.03,28.74">
                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M64 26.4,0 0,31.3z">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Brush="#FF000000" Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" />
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup Transform="1,0,0,1,2.82,-0.01">
                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 .4,21.8 53.1,45.7 29.7,49.9 6.7,54 0.1,29.7 0.1,29.7 0.1,29.7 50.4,21.8z">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Brush="#FF000000" Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Flat" EndLineCap="Flat" LineJoin="Miter" />
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup Transform="1,0,0,1,0,20.91">
                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 0,15.4 0,0z" />
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
```

this code was made from Xaml to SVG converter, so i have some kind of libraries whit that images from different Resource Dictionaries and want add them into the collection, then bind it throug ViewModel and etc etc...
Every resource have of course unique x:key. I've tried to add them into StackPanel, and then go through that stackPanel, like

```
foreach(var image in StackPanel)
{
    Image image1 = new Image();
    image1.Source = image;
    MyCollection.Add(image)
}
```

but that's kinda messy. Hope you guys can help me to found some better solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load up your resource dictionaries in code and iterate through their keys like so:

```
if (!(Application.LoadComponent(
    new Uri("YourUriToYourResourceDictionary.xaml", 
        UriKind.Relative)) is ResourceDictionary rd))
{
    return;
}

var keys = rd.Keys;

foreach(var key in keys)
{
    //Use Application.Current.TryFindResource(key) and do whatever you need to do.
}
```

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot. Saved a lot of time for me:)